# Python partitions excluding numbers already been together

Tags: python

Say I have a few integers 1-10 how would I order them based on groups of 1, 2, 3, and 4 of which they cannot be grouped together with an integer they've already been grouped with.
For instance
(1,2,3) #1 2 and 3 can no longer be paired with each other
(4,5,6) #4 5 and 6 can no longer be paired with each other
(7,8,9) #7 8 and 9 can no longer be paired with each other
but now...
(1,4,7) works
(2,5,8) works
(3,6,9) works

---

Whenever I try to write a program like this I end up with (1 2) (3 4) (5 6) (1 3) (1 4) (1 5) (1 6) (2 3) (2 4) (2 5) (2 6) (3 5) (3 6) all of these partitions are correct but as soon as I work in groups of threes my answers become (0 1 2) (0 1 3) (0 1 4) but 0 and 1 can only be paired together once.

Here is my code for a group of 2! with numbers 0-3

```
def combinations2():
    count = 0
    count2 = 1
    array = []


    while(count < 4):
        count2 = count + 1

        while(count2 < 4):
            temp = "(" +  str(count) + " " +  str(count2)+ ")"
            array.append(temp)
            #print(temp)

            count2 += 1
        count += 1
    print(array)

combinations2()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out itertools.

```
from itertools import combinations

#this is the list of digits to consider    
my_numbers = range(1,10)

def make_groups(n):
    #initialize a couple lists for groups that we want, my_groups, 
    # and a list to keep track of pairs that we've already included
    my_groups = []
    pairs_seen = []
    #get all combinations of size n of our digits
    size_n_combins = combinations(my_numbers,n)     
    #for each combination to see if it meets our condition that each pair contained
    # should not be in any of our other groups, if it does keep track of the pairs it
    # contains and keep track of the combination by adding it to my_groups
    for combin in size_n_combins:
        if all([pair not in pairs_seen for pair in combinations(combin,2)]):
            pairs_seen += [pair for pair in combinations(combin,2)]
            my_groups.append(combin)
        else:
            continue
    #finally return the groups we wanted
    return my_groups
```

If you call `make_groups(3)` it will then return:

```
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 4, 5), (1, 6, 7), (1, 8, 9), (2, 4, 6), (2, 5, 7), (3, 4, 7), (3, 5, 6)]
```

Comment: Printing my groups does nothing oddly.

Comment: Are you doing `print make_groups(3)` (or `print(make_groups(3))` if you're on python 3)?

Comment: Also, I just made a slight edit that may have fixed it if you want to try again.